# I am getting the below error, when I m trying to add and show element at/from data base. Here is the detailed error message:

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, dao

État HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Rapport d''exception

```
message org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758)
    ma.axa.HibernateDAO.TachesDAO.saveData(TachesDAO.java:26)
    ma.axa.Servlets.FrontServlet.doPost(FrontServlet.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cause mère

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2907)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3478)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:623)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:277)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:258)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:303)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:773)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758)
    ma.axa.HibernateDAO.TachesDAO.saveData(TachesDAO.java:26)
    ma.axa.Servlets.FrontServlet.doPost(FrontServlet.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cause mère

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'nom_tache' cannot be null
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:934)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2907)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3478)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:623)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:277)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:258)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:303)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:773)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758)
    ma.axa.HibernateDAO.TachesDAO.saveData(TachesDAO.java:26)
    ma.axa.Servlets.FrontServlet.doPost(FrontServlet.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note La trace complète de la cause mère de cette erreur est disponible dans les fichiers journaux de ce serveur.
```

Apache Tomcat/8.5.16

The Structure of the project is:

This is the class Taches.java

```
public class Taches {

private Integer id_tache;
private String nom_tache;
private String description_tache;

//les constructeurs

public Taches() 
{
    super();
}

public Taches(Integer id_tache, String nom_tache, String description_tache) {
    super();
    this.id_tache = id_tache;
    this.nom_tache = nom_tache;
    this.description_tache = description_tache;
}

//getters and setters
public Integer getId_tache() {
    return id_tache;
}

public void setId_tache(Integer id_tache) {
    this.id_tache = id_tache;
}
public String getNom_tache() {
    return nom_tache;
}
public void setNom_tache(String nom_tache) {
    this.nom_tache = nom_tache;
}
public String getDescription_tache() {
    return description_tache;
}
public void setDescription_tache(String description_tache) {
    this.description_tache = description_tache;
}
```

This is the class TacheDAO.java

```
public class TachesDAO {

Session session;
private Session setSession(){
    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    return session;
}
//enregistrer des donnees dans la table categories
public void saveData(Taches tache){
    session=setSession();
    try{
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(tache);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(HibernateException he){
        he.printStackTrace();
        if(session.getTransaction()!=null){
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }finally{
        if(session!=null){
            session.close();
        }
    }
}

//selectionner la liste des donnees
public List<Taches> selectAllData(){
    List<Taches> ltaches=new ArrayList();

    session=setSession();
    try{
        session.beginTransaction();

        Query<Taches> query=session.createQuery("From Taches");
        ltaches=query.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        return ltaches;
    }catch(HibernateException he){

        he.printStackTrace();
        if(session.getTransaction()!=null){
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

        return null;
    }finally{
        if(session!=null){
            session.close();
        }
    }


}
public Taches getTachesById(Integer id){
    Taches tache=null;
    Session session=setSession();
    try{
        session.beginTransaction();
        tache=(Taches)session.get(Taches.class, id);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }catch(HibernateException he){
        he.printStackTrace();
        if(session.getTransaction()!=null){
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }finally{
        if(session!=null){
            session.close();
        }
    }

    return tache;
}
```

This the file hibernateUtil.java

```
public class HibernateUtil {


private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory=buildSessionFactory();
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(){

    try {
                      // Create SessionFactory with hibernate.cfg.xml configure+build
                      return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        } 
    catch (Throwable ex)
    {
                      // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
                      System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }

  }


public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    return sessionFactory;
}



}
```

This the servlet `FrontSERVLET`

```
public class FrontServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/backOffice/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
Taches tache=new Taches();

}
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Taches tache=new Taches();
    TachesDAO TDAO=new TachesDAO();

    String titre=req.getParameter("nom_tache");
    String description=req.getParameter("description_tache");

    tache.setNom_tache(titre);
    tache.setDescription_tache(description);

    TDAO.saveData(tache);


}
```

and this is my page index.jsp

```
  <div class="ajouter">

      <a>Ajouter</a>
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" boundary="boundary">
          Nom de la tache: <input type="text" name="module"><br>
          Description: <input type="text" name="description"><br>


          <input type="submit" value="Ajouter">
      </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a naming problem: (notice the name is `module`)

```
Nom de la tache: <input type="text" name="module"><br>
```

but you read as

```
String titre=req.getParameter("nom_tache");
```

So nom_tache field becomes null, so you get

```
....MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'nom_tache' cannot be null ....
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

In your class `Taches`,
You forgot annotaions, this is the most important information that tells hibernate where to insert your data

```
    @Entity
    public class Taches {
    @Id
    @Column
    private Integer id_tache;
    @Column
    private String nom_tache;
    @Column
    private String description_tache;
//Constructor //Getters and setters}
```

Comment: the problem is resolved . But I can't add data at my data base . when I m trying to add information just the cardinality increments . This is from Eclipse console

Comment: Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        TACHES
        (NOM_TACHE, DESCRIPTION_TACHE) 
    values
        (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        TACHES
        (NOM_TACHE, DESCRIPTION_TACHE) 
    values
        (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        TACHES
        (NOM_TACHE, DESCRIPTION_TACHE) 
    values
        (?, ?)